# Access existing angular module in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: node.js, angularjs, selenium, node-webkit

- I am using **Selenium** with a chrome WebDriver to drive my integration testing in a node-web kit.
- My app starts up and I can test the DOM, but I want to confirm some actions - is there a way to get a reference to the angular module that is instantiated so I can test some of that code in the context of a running application?
- I don't want to create a new angular module, I want to access the one the app created on start-up.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Angular.js. But if you can access angular module with JavaScript,it is OK to do it with selenium webdriver.You could let webdriver pass JavaScript test code to the node-webkit.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver_path = "./chromedriver"

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)

js = 
'''//test DOM
document.body.innerHTML += "<h1>it works!</h1>";

//test NODE
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var win = gui.Window.get();
win.showDevTools();

console.log(process.execPath);'''

chrome.execute_script(js)
```